# Showing Levels end values on contourf

Tags: python, contourf

I'm using a contourf to plot my data (var) and I would like to have 20 levels going from -100 to 100, so this what I did.

```
plt.contourf(var, levels=np.linspace(-100, 100, 21))
```

But when I plot it it will miss the end values (-100 and 100), how can I solve it and show these values?

Thanks in advance.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hEPF.png)

Comment: Does `endpoint=True` in the [`linspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) help you?

Comment: Or is the question why there are no outer tick labels "-100", "100"?, then use [`tick_params`](/https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tick_params.html) with `labelbottom`, `labeltop` set to `True`.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help.
Exactly, second comment. The values are in the linspace but are not showing on the plot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a fine control of the values shown in the colorbar:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y = np.mgrid[-2:2:100j,-2:2:100j]
z = 100 * np.cos(x**2 + y**2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
c = ax.contourf(x, y, z, levels=np.linspace(-100, 100, 21))
cb = fig.colorbar(c)
ticks = np.linspace(-100, 100, 9)
# if you change ticks, you want to change the following as well
labels = [str(int(t)) for t in ticks]
cb.set_ticks(ticks, labels=labels)
```